# DIV layout is different when I run app from web server as opposed to local dev server

Tags: css, html

I've got a CSS problem.  My DIVs are laying out differently depending on when I run my web app from the web server versus my local VS2010 development server.

My three inside DIVs (preButtons, navContainer, postButtons) are all displayed inline when I run locally, but when I publish and run from IIS 7.5 web server there is a line break after each div.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Here is the HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">    
    div#pager div
    {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #navContainer
    {
        width: 340px;
        height: 28px;                
        overflow: hidden;   
        position: relative;     
    }

    #reel
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;      
        width: 0;  
    }

</style>
<div id="pager" class="buttons">
    <div id="preButtons"></div>
    <div id="navContainer">
        <div id="reel">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="postButtons"></div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Here is a screenshot of the problem in action.  The blue border is because I have the "pager" div selected in IE developer tools.
[image]

UPDATE:

At the end of the day my issue was two-fold.

My HTML & CSS needed to be cleaned up as was indicated, but also my site was opening in compatibility mode.  This was because the option "Display Intranet Sites in Compatibility View" was checked positive under Tools --> Compatibility View Settings.  I think was set automatically when my company deployed IE8 to our desktops.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: ist the HTML/CSS exactly the same (do a DIFF)?

Comment: That kind of thing usually doesnt happen. It must be serving you a cached version of that page.

Comment: Maybe you should try using a .css file instead of making the styling inline? Also check the Source of the page that you are viewing that has the unwanted changes to make sure the code is exactly the same

Comment: Did you intentionally leave out the html, head, and body tags or are they really not there?  A screenshot would probably help so we know exactly what you're trying to do.....your layout is likely not the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: I don't believe it's cached since other updates I've made to this page are reflective in the output.  Moving the CSS into it's own file didn't help at all.

Comment: Did you do a view source on the page that is on the server??

Comment: @bpeterson76 - I did.  This is actually a partial razor view in MVC 3, so it's being dynamically added to my overall page.  Does the screenshot I added address what you wanted to see?

Comment: @anirudh4444 - I have been eyeballing CSS in IE's developer tools and not seen a difference yet.  I suppose I'll have to run a diff in a text editor to validate it for certain.

Comment: @Ben Does the class buttons do anything to change it from inline to block>?????

Comment: @Laurence - You know what? It does.  .buttons a gets set to display:block;  Removing that particular line didn't change anything however.

Comment: In IE developer tools is the page mode the same for both pages (ie. is it rendering in IE7 or 8 or 9 mode in both cases - doesn't matter which as long as they're both the same)?

Comment: @robertc - That might very well have been it.  It seems like I can recreate the issue by toggling between compat mode and straight IE8.

Comment: For IE7/Compat mode add `*display:inline` to fake inline-block support [see this blog post for more](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/).

Comment: "Display Intranet Sites in Compatibility View" was set in my options.  Must have been part of the deployment of IE8 to our desktops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can greatly simplify your code here.  Take your three divs and put them in a container.  Float all three left.  Clear the float afterward.  No more absolute positioning required.  Done deal.

For example:
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="floatleft"></div>
       <div class="floatleft"></div>
       <div class="floatleft"></div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.floatleft {
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  clear:both;
}
```

As an aside, depending on what you're paging it might be far easier to do a javascript grid such as [DataTables](http://www.DataTables.net) which would negate the need to do any of this at all....

Comment: This appears to solve it!  Thanks!  Question:  I was only doing absolute positioning on my #reel div (because it's wider than the navContainer and gets scrolled around).  Do you know why it was displaying differently on the different setups?

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link!  I was rolling my own since I didn't know any better.

Comment: I can't imagine laying out certain pages with out this technique. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use a css reset such as [this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) at the beginning of your css.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a partial view control and embedded as part of other pages in my application.  Clearing out the CSS ruins the rest of my page.  Gave it a whirl though and the divs still had a line break afterwards.